# Monotouch: Several columns in Monotouch.Dialog?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I need to make a list/view (with several columns) like...

```
Name      Age  Gender
---------------------
John       39    Male
Susan      19  Female
```

How can I make a list/view like this in Monotouch?

Is it possible with Monotouch.Dialog?

Thanks a million!!!

:)
Mojo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do something like this is to create a [custom UITableViewCell](http://www.alexyork.net/blog/post/Creating-Custom-UITableViewCells-with-MonoTouch-the-correct-way.aspx).  To do this with MT.Dialog you would need to create a custom element.

This explains how to [create a custom MonoTouch.Dialog Element](http://www.alexyork.net/blog/post/Creating-Custom-UITableViewCells-with-MonoTouch-the-correct-way.aspx).